# dhcpcd ipv6 excessive adding/removing route in log

Tags: linux, ubuntu, linux-networking, ipv6, dhcpcd

This correlates with router advertising. For now, I removed `ipv6rs` from the config and added the route manually. Is there a better way to eliminate the excessive log?

```
Apr 22 16:53:39 prince dhcpcd[2358]: eth1: adding default route via fe80::201:5cff:fe63:c046
Apr 22 16:53:39 prince dhcpcd[2358]: eth1: removing default route via fe80::201:5cff:fe63:c046
Apr 22 16:53:42 prince dhcpcd[2358]: eth1: adding default route via fe80::201:5cff:fe63:c046
Apr 22 16:53:42 prince dhcpcd[2358]: eth1: removing default route via fe80::201:5cff:fe63:c046
Apr 22 16:53:45 prince dhcpcd[2358]: eth1: adding default route via fe80::201:5cff:fe63:c046
Apr 22 16:53:45 prince dhcpcd[2358]: eth1: removing default route via fe80::201:5cff:fe63:c046
Apr 22 16:53:49 prince dhcpcd[2358]: eth1: adding default route via fe80::201:5cff:fe63:c046
Apr 22 16:53:49 prince dhcpcd[2358]: eth1: removing default route via fe80::201:5cff:fe63:c046
Apr 22 16:53:53 prince dhcpcd[2358]: eth1: adding default route via fe80::201:5cff:fe63:c046
Apr 22 16:53:53 prince dhcpcd[2358]: eth1: removing default route via fe80::201:5cff:fe63:c046
Apr 22 16:53:56 prince dhcpcd[2358]: eth1: adding default route via fe80::201:5cff:fe63:c046
Apr 22 16:53:56 prince dhcpcd[2358]: eth1: removing default route via fe80::201:5cff:fe63:c046
Apr 22 16:54:00 prince dhcpcd[2358]: eth1: adding default route via fe80::201:5cff:fe63:c046
Apr 22 16:54:00 prince dhcpcd[2358]: eth1: removing default route via fe80::201:5cff:fe63:c046
Apr 22 16:54:04 prince dhcpcd[2358]: eth1: adding default route via fe80::201:5cff:fe63:c046
Apr 22 16:54:04 prince dhcpcd[2358]: eth1: removing default route via fe80::201:5cff:fe63:c046
Apr 22 16:54:07 prince dhcpcd[2358]: eth1: adding default route via fe80::201:5cff:fe63:c046
Apr 22 16:54:07 prince dhcpcd[2358]: eth1: removing default route via fe80::201:5cff:fe63:c046
Apr 22 16:54:10 prince dhcpcd[2358]: eth1: adding default route via fe80::201:5cff:fe63:c046
Apr 22 16:54:10 prince dhcpcd[2358]: eth1: removing default route via fe80::201:5cff:fe63:c046
Apr 22 16:54:13 prince dhcpcd[2358]: eth1: adding default route via fe80::201:5cff:fe63:c046
Apr 22 16:54:13 prince dhcpcd[2358]: eth1: removing default route via fe80::201:5cff:fe63:c046
Apr 22 16:54:16 prince dhcpcd[2358]: eth1: adding default route via fe80::201:5cff:fe63:c046
Apr 22 16:54:16 prince dhcpcd[2358]: eth1: removing default route via fe80::201:5cff:fe63:c046
Apr 22 16:54:20 prince dhcpcd[2358]: eth1: adding default route via fe80::201:5cff:fe63:c046
Apr 22 16:54:20 prince dhcpcd[2358]: eth1: removing default route via fe80::201:5cff:fe63:c046
```

And here is the current config:

```
hostname
duid
persistent
option rapid_commit
option domain_name_servers, domain_name, domain_search, host_name
option classless_static_routes
option ntp_servers
require dhcp_server_identifier
slaac private
nohook lookup-hostname
noipv6rs
interface eth1
#  ipv6rs
#  ipv6ra_own_default
  iaid 1
  ia_pd 1/::/64 eth2/0/64
```

Comment: Not clear why, but after reboot (and enabling `ipv6rs`) this disappeared.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When dhcpcd is being stopped, it will not clear routes added by itself, as expected. However, once dhcpcd is restarted and dhcp is acquired, it will try to add routes again and will remove it's own route because of duplicate, but still mark the route as not added.

The solution, until this behavior is fixed, is to monitor the log for adding/removing and then remove the route it is trying to add. In the above case:

```
sudo ip -6 route del default via fe80::201:5cff:fe63:c046 dev eth1
```

Once done, dhcpcd will add the route back and be quiet.

Comment: I have same problem actually on 2 of my pi's when I try solution above: `pi@raspberrypi3:~ $ sudo ip -6 route del default route via fe80::2620:c7ff:fe96:4adb dev eth0` Error: either "to" is duplicate, or "route" is a garbage. and the problem persists any idea what else can be tried.

Comment: @ToshiBass what version of OS you run on your pi? Try `sudo ip -6 route del default via fe80::201:5cff:fe63:c046 dev eth1` (without the second `route`)

Comment: Updated and removed the second route

Answer (score -2):

```
sudo ip -6 route del default via fe80::201:5cff:fe63:c046 dev eth1
```

(without the second route) solved this problem for me. My OS is Debian 8 Jessie